# Проверка валидности ника

Tags: регулярные-выражения

День добрый.

Требуется рег. выражение для проверки валидности ника.

Разрешенные символы:

```
а-я А-Я a-z A-Z 0-9 _
```

Делал так:

```
^[а-яА-Яa-zA-Z0-9_-]{1,}$
```

Но если ввести к примеру это:

```
±name±
```

То preg_match возвращает истину, хотя в тексте используются запрещенные символы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы работаете с UTF-8 строкой, но не используете соответствующий модификатор.
Вот так будет работать так, как вы задумали:

```
#^[а-яА-Яa-zA-Z0-9_-]+$#u
```

**[Убедитесь сами](http://ideone.com/iLDuqM)**

Answer (score 0):

Включите юникод:

```
/^[а-яА-Яa-zA-Z0-9_\-]{1,}$/u
```

Не могу не отметить, что это очень забавная штука:

```
$pat = '#^([а-я])$#';
preg_match($pat, '±',$matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

получаем

```
php test.php 
array(1) {
  [0] =>
  string(2) "±"
}

$pat = '#^([а-я]).*$#';
---
array(2) {
  [0] =>
  string(2) "±"
  [1] =>
  string(1) "�" /// матерь божья
}
```

Comment: Вот почему:  

±     - 2 байта  
[а-я] - 1 байт

([а-я]).* - как это можно прочитать:  
"(1 байтовый символ) все остальное";  
или в контексте нашего символа:  
(1 байтовый символ) 1 байтовый символ"
string(2) "±" - весь паттерн (второй случай из объяснения)  
string(1) "�" - захват из скобок (1 байтовый символ); символ с таким кодом не существует, вот вывод и "ломается"

Comment: Я знаю, что юникод кодирует кириллицу в два байта, и именно поэтому соорудио вторую регулярку. Забавно то, что черт знает что совпадает с а-я.

Comment: Сравнить [x] с [[x][y]] => совпадение. Поэтому не черти что.  
Мы же сами не указываем режим сравнения...

Comment: Регулярка должна либо брать валидный двухбайтовый регион, с которым сравнивать, либо стрелять ошибкой при указании двухбайтового региона. Поэтому - не очень ожидаемое от регулярки поведение.

Comment: Ищем однобайтовый символ внутри двухбайтового. Естественно находим. С моей точки зрения все логично, но чтобы вести аргументированную дискуссию мне не хватает знаний.

Comment: Судя по string(2) он как раз-таки двухбайтовый. Хотя интернет говорит мне, что первый байт в юникоде у него будет 00.

Comment: Я и не спорю. ± - двухбайтовый (в котором ищем) "а" (например) - однобайтовый (тот, что ищем). Где это противоречит моим словам? :)

Comment: "А" тоже не однобайтовый, и мне слабо верится, что оба байта 00 и b1 лежат внутри а-яА-Я. То что он воспринимается как однобайтовый, хотя задается двухбайтовым - то, о чем я с самого начала говорю, нормальная программа в этом случае выкидывает ошибку. Если они считывают побайтово и у них в результате получается [ а_байт1 а_байт2-я_байт1 я_байт2 ], то это совсем не але.